# Microservices authorization

Tags: token, microservices

A microservice supposed to own its own data, no shared database.
A token includes the userid, clams, but claims are just authentication, not authorization.
So if I have a monolit application, I can check if the user is part of a group (claim), and if it is, I fetch from the database what that group is able to do.
But if I have a microservice, I can't do that, I don't want to replicate this authorization information into all of the microservices.

For example, all users belong to a team, and everything in service in the application belong to a team (for example, members of team "A" has access to forums of team "A", gallery of team "A", etc.

Even if I store the team in a claim (what I don't want, because membership can change while the token is still alive), I need to have team data in all microservices. But that sounds very bad.

So what can I do?

thanks

Comment: Do you use an API gateway?

Comment: probably I would, yes...

Comment: Then you can do the Authorization in the API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass user token(that up read from claims) in request header through the chain of microservices such that each microservice just have to validate the token to determine the user has been successfully authenticated, and permission enforcement is done in the microservice itself.